# Java 8 Stream API equivalent of nested for loops

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is it possible to replace the processing performed in this example with a single Java8 Stream API instruction, instead of nested for loops ?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<BeanA> aList = Arrays.asList(new BeanA(), new BeanA(), new BeanA());
    List<BeanB> bList = Arrays.asList(new BeanB(), new BeanB(), new BeanB());

    List<Bean> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (BeanA a : aList) {
        for (BeanB b : bList) {
            result.add(new Bean(a, b));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("size:" + result.size());
    System.out.println("result:" + result);
}

public static class BeanA {
}

public static class BeanB {
}

public static class Bean {
    private BeanA a;
    private BeanB b;

    public Bean(BeanA a, BeanB b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `Stream`s, but even with `Stream`s you can't avoid the nested iteration, since you want to produce `aList.size() * bList.size()` instances of `Bean`.

```
List<Bean> result =
    aList.stream()
         .flatMap(a->bList.stream().map(b->new Bean(a,b)))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Oh, I was trying with 2 flatMap calls, but didn't though to nest lambdas like this. Thanks :)

Comment: Hell eclipse, it compiles well with Javac and inside IntelliJ IDEA, but doesn't compile using eclipse because it results as a List<Object> instead of List<Bean> ...

Comment: @Toilal Which Eclipse are you using? It compiles fine with my Mars 4.5.1.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 15 with eclipse compiler, and it's failing too, but I don't know which compiler version it embeds. I can reproduce it with Luna too. It's probably a fixed bug if it works with Mars !

Comment: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5565196;jsessionid=E3D196FD81F600116CE2AA2486C7FE33 => It seems to be Luna version of the compiler inside intellij 15.

Comment: @Toilal, Just add explicit type arguments: `.<Bean>flatMap(...)` and it will work fine with Eclipse as well.